# AutoPostBack on Checkbox Checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

```css
//C# Code

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

```html
 <h2 style="font-style: italic">
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Residental Address  : "></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </h2>
        <h2 style="font-style: italic">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Text="Both Same" />
        </h2>
        <h2 style="font-style: italic">
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Native Address :"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </h2>
```

if residental address is same so on clicking on checkbox it must autopostback it to native address its but i tried and it showed blank

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the PageLoad event after clicking on checkbox, and see if  textbox is getting reset somewhere in your code?
otherwise it should work.